# java -version tells me 8 but jdk is 1.7 - OSX 10.9.x

Tags: java, macos

Something I don't understand - I'm on OSX 10.9.5 and when I run `java -version` at the terminal, I get:

> java version "1.8.0_40"
>   Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_40-b25)
>   Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.40-b25, mixed mode)

But in my /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/ dir I see 3 JDKs:

- jdk1.7.0_71.jdk
- jdk1.7.0_75.jdk
- jdk1.7.0_76.jdk

Eclipse uses jdk1.7.0_76.jdk.  I remember installing Java 7 for some personal dev projects in Eclipse, but I don't recall ever installing Java 8.  So why would `java -version` say I'm running 8?  And how can it if no jdk exists for Java 8 in that directory?

Confused.  TIA.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The version you are questioning is actually the `Java Runtime Environment (JRE)` version, not the `Java Developer Kit (JDK)` version; they are two different things. You are running Java 8 (`JRE`), although you can selectively choose another runtime if there is one available.

If you want to see all of the versions of Java you might currently have:

```
$ /usr/libexec/java_home -V
Matching Java Virtual Machines (3):
    1.8.0_45,             x86_64:   "Java SE 8" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home
    1.6.0_65-b14-466.1,   x86_64:   "Java SE 6" /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
    1.6.0_65-b14-466.1,     i386:   "Java SE 6" /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
```

To see which one is currently running as default:

```
$ which java ; java -version
/usr/bin/java
java version "1.8.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_45-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.45-b02, mixed mode)
```

To see which `JDKs` are installed:

```
$ ls /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/
jdk1.8.0_45.jdk
```

**The Java Runtime Environment (JRE)**

> The JRE allows you to run applications written in the Java programming language. Like the JDK, it contains the Java Virtual
>   Machine (JVM), classes comprising the Java platform API, and
>   supporting files. Unlike the JDK, it does not contain development
>   tools such as compilers and debuggers.

**The Java Development Kit (JDK)**

> The JDK is a development environment for building
>   applications, applets, and components using the Java programming
>   language. The JDK includes tools useful for developing and testing programs written in the Java programming language and running on
>   the Java platform.

Since Eclipse relies on the tools within the `JDK` they would most definitely be using one of your installed `JDKs`, for it couldn't work just using the `JRE`.

Comment: Thank you very helpful - I guess I had assumed that since I downloaded the Java 7 JDK that my JRE would be 7 as well. But perhaps JRE 8 was installed as part of say, my IT dept's standard build? Who knows. Any issues developing off of JDK 7 with JRE 8?

Comment: You shouldn't have any problems as Java 8 is backwards compatible with older versions of JREs and JDKs. In rare circumstances there might be an exception, although you likely won't experience any issues unless you're using something that's been deprecated for quite some time, etc. Here's a little more info on the subject: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8-compatibility-guide-2156366.html#A999198

Answer (score 0):

in you .path_profile folder export the JAVA_HOME to your JDK8 folder, java -version is a result of you JVN as it seem to me put you java_home still point to JDK1.7 do the following

```
$ vim .bash_profile 

export JAVA_HOME=YOUR_JDK8_PATH 

$ source .bash_profile
```

Comment: Thank you for your response but I'm not sure I follow - I want to use Java 7.  I don't believe "YOUR_JDK8_PATH" path exists if it's not in the aforementioned directory: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/.

Comment: try find / -name "Jdk" in the shell and you will get all the paths for the jdk